# Linux cli pipeline command tail and grep

Tags: linux, grep, command, tail

I am using tail to monitor a log file and using grep to filer the keyword.

`tail -F somefile.log | grep "keyword"` is working
`tail -F somefile.log | awk '{print $4}'` is working

but if to put them together is not working, like `tail -F somefile.log | grep "keyword" | awk '{print $4}'`

Is this the wrong way to use `|`? How to make `tail -F somefile.log | grep "keyword" | awk '{print $4}'` to work? Thanks

if I want to run a command after awk like `tail -F somefile.log | grep "keyword" | awk '{print $4}' | ./abashfile.sh` how to achieve something like this, looks like multiple `|` is not quite right for combining everything in 1 line. Thanks

Comment: It seems fine. What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `awk` alone:

```
tail -f somefile.log | awk '/keyword/ {print $4}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to figure out multiple `|`. eg I want to run a command after print `tail -f somefile.log | awk '/keyword/ {print $4}' | echo "received" >> file`  looks the extra `|` is not something to be used?

Comment: You can combine as many pipes as you want/need in one line. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to do something like `tail -f somefile.log | awk '/keyword/ {print $4}' | echo {print $4}(get the result) >> filename (to another file)`